# Accessing insights data for a specific url on my domain

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

read_insights permission is granted, and I can access domain specific insights data with :

https://graph.facebook.com/insights?domain=example.com&access_token=TOKEN

However, I need to get url specific insights : **actions, impressions, referral traffic.** [This post](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7874001/how-to-access-data-from-facebook-insights-for-domains/7874140#7874140) suggests url specific data can be retrieved as :

https://graph.facebook.com/insights?id=YOUR_URL&access_token=TOKEN

this only leads to null dataset for any page on my domain. facebook.com/insights show data, but my graph call is always

```
"data": [      
   ]
```

How can I get this data ?

Comment: Have you tried just running: http://www.facebook.com/insights/ first?

Comment: yes, facebook.com/insights show the data for the specific url. The problem is I can't get it via graph api.

Comment: After searching for an answer, I decided to post a Facebook bug :
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/240920425969457
 (Feel free to subscribe, if you are having similar issue) I will update this post when bug entry is resolved, or replied.

Comment: did you find a solution for this ? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: @GalBen-Haim unfortunately no, facebook closed the bug with no explanation. Left us in the darkness. You are welcome to resubmit the bug, and try to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use Facebook URL Linter and get ID of URL.
after that request https://graph.facebook.com/ID/insights?access_token=TOKEN

Comment: Thx, but still same "no data" result! But I know likes and impressions exist, I can see with facebook.com/insights